# parsing jquery in html page to fetch the load url in python

Tags: jquery, python, html

I have the following java script code snippet in a html page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery("#data1").load("/link-to-data-1 table");
    })
</script>
```

Please suggest some good methods to get url : /link-to-data-1 from the above script using HTML Parser or any other parser. By using HTML Parser we tried to parse the data in handle_data we are getting the following data as string `jQuery(document).ready(function(){ jQuery("#data1").load("/link-to-data-1 table"); })` we would like to extract url link /link-to-data-1 from the above data in structured manner.

Comment: if the url is ALWAYS in `load()` function why don't you just write a regex that extracts the string between the `load()`?

Answer (score 0):

Using a regular expression you will be able to match something like `load\(\"(.*)\"\)`, which will grab what you need, I've put an example here, http://rubular.com/r/YMWtYMJSdG. The Rubular tool is powered by Ruby regular expressions, but these basic features are portable across all engines.

The match in my example is **non greedy**, so the following example is also correct http://rubular.com/r/yjPVrKMgWX

Comment: Thanks beaks for your time and answer, 
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery("#data1").load("/link-to-data-1 table");
    })

Comment: You're welcome, please remember to accept my answer with the "tick" icon on the left if it helped you.

Comment: Thanks beaks for your time and answer, 
from the following i need to get only data1's url
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery("#data1").load("/link-to-data-1 table");
        jQuery("#data2").load("/link-to-data-2 table");
        jQuery("#data3").load("/link-to-data-3 table");
        jQuery("#data4").load("/link-to-data-4 table");
    })

Comment: Your regular expression engine will give you a number of "matches" (see my Rubular example) - the first match will be `/link-to-data-1`, this is often called `$1` or `\1`, or made available via your language. (For Java, you can read http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html to get more feeling for how to start).

Comment: It's easier to keep the regular expression "greedy" so that it finds all loaded links, and then you will have them as an array in your code, and can simply take the first, you can also of course extend the regular expression to do this: http://rubular.com/r/w9zlG0r3sl